# Error while trying to delete "NA" cells in R Studio

Tags: r, na

Just getting started with R Studio and I'm running into an error. Trying to delete "NA" values from my table but am running into the error below

```
Error in tripscl %>% filter(!is.na(start_station_name)) %>% filter(!is.na(end_station_name)) %>%  : 
  could not find function "%>%"
```

```
expected ',' after expression
```

And this is the code that is producing the error

```
tripscl_na <- tripscl %>%
  filter(!(rideable_type == "classic_bike" & (is.na("start_station_name")
                                              is.na("end_station_name"))))
```

Not really sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: There is no `,` or `&` or anything after the first is.na and the second is.na

Comment: What @akrun said, but also it says `could not find function "%>%"` which usually means you need to call `library(dplyr)` (or another package which has the pipe such as `magrittr`) before running your code. Or replace that pipe with the base pipe `|>`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a missing comma, try instead

```r
library(dplyr)

tripscl_na <- tripscl %>%
  filter(!(
    rideable_type == "classic_bike" &
      is.na("start_station_name") & is.na("end_station_name")
  ))
```

If you want to filter those that are `classic_bike` and `start_station_name` and `end_station_name` are not missing, that is.